# Use typings from a declared module in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, durandal

I'm going through the Durandal "get started" guide on the DurandalJS.com site, except I'm trying to do it with TypeScript.  The last demo (the Mount Rainier one) has a module with code like this:

```
define(function (require) {
  var http = require('plugins/http'),
      ko = require('knockout');
  //other stuff
}
```

Everything is working fine when I run the code in the browser, but I wanted to see if I could get TypeScript to be aware of the types.  I imported the Durandal, Knockout, jQuery, and RequireJS NuGet packages from DefinitelyTyped and I was able to get the ko variable typed by doing

```
ko : KnockoutStatic = require('knockout');
```

This works because KnockoutStatic is an interface declared in the Knockout.d.ts file.  However, in the durandal.d.ts file, 'plugins/http' is declared like this with no named interface:

```
declare module 'plugins/http' { /*stuff*/ }
```

I have three questions:

- Should/is there a way to get TypeScript to know the types for ko and http automatically based on the call to require with the module name inside?
- Is there a way to explicitly type my http variable with the way that the durandal.d.ts file is structured (module vs interface).
- If not, what would be the right way to set up the durandal.d.ts file to allow strong typing of the http variable - just declare an interface instead of a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for all three questions :

```
import http = require('plugins/http');
```

Additionally you should not have a manual "define" since typescript will generate it for you. These are called external modules.

PS : I have a video about typescripts module system http://youtube.com/watch?hd=1&v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Comment: Hi Bas, should there be a require after the import http = ?